# Deploy project on EC2 in private subnet using Azure Release(CD) pipelines

Tags: azure, ssh, devops, cicd

We are moving our core logic from public subnet EC2 to private subnet EC2. Earlier to connect with EC2 in pvt subnet we needed a bastion server but with introduction of [EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-with-ec2-instance-connect-endpoint.html) we can just use the private ip address.
Sample command looks like:
`ssh -i <THE_PEM_FILE>.pem  <user-name>@<private-ip-ec2> -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel -- instance-id <ec2-instance-id> --max-tunnel-duration 3600'`

Azure has a [Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but that is plain simple ssh connection. But how do I run this ssh command to establish connection for deployment?

I am able to make a simple ssh connection: `ssh user@public-ip` using the Azure Task. But not sure how do I run a custom ssh command.